# react static website on s3 loads all routes on browsers but not on google crawlers or curl

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, seo, single-page-application

I developed a react app that is hosted on amazon s3 as a static website. I am trying to improve the SEO of this webpage but when seeing the google search console I noticed that there are 404 errors on the routes, I clicked them and the browser was able to display them but if I made a get request using curl I get the 404 error, I saw the problem is because the client side rendering not able to locate the javascript needed to show the route so my question is if there is a way I can preload the routes of the site in order to be crawlable by google and other search engine without using gatsby or next.js.

Comment: thanks, but that does not solve my issue, there just solve to show a custom error page if a route is not found, but my routes exist the problem is that as them are on a virtual route of the SPA the crawlers can't get them but broweser can

Comment: Your case matches that solution exactly.  They take the 404 errors from the s3 bucket and instead serve `index.html` with a 200 status.  That allows all the routes to resolve and not have 404 errors.

Comment: please forgive me and thanks for replying, you are correct, this worked pretty well.